# Can Sync Services add a column on the central table?

Tags: ado.net, microsoft-sync-framework, syncservices

Is it possible to have Sync Services for ADO.NET read data from a table on multiple devices and insert it into a central SQL Server, having an additional column in the central table with the origin of the row data?

Let's say I have equipped door-to-door sales people with a device where they register sales. The local table would contain rows with sales information, and the central database would contain the same data + a column with the ID of the sales person.

Is that possible, or would I need the sales person's ID in the local database too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sync Framework identifies each client with a GUID (see: [How To:Use Session Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902811.aspx)) and you can use that to map a particular client to a particular salesperson (see:Identifying Which Client Made a Data Change on either [How to: Use Custom Change Tracking System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305973.aspx) or [How to: Use SQL Server Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322.aspx).

Or try the approach here for intercepting the change dataset and inserting/substituting the salesperson value: [Part 1 – Upload Synchronization where the Client and Server Primary Keys are different](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/upload-synchronization-where-the-client-and-server-primary-keys-are-different/)